# JavaScript for `set('pdf ppt tif tiff jpg jpeg'.split())`?

Tags: javascript, set, bookmarklet

The Python idiom in the subject line

```
set('pdf ppt tif tiff jpg jpeg'.split())
```

illustrates a fairly compact way to create a set of strings.<sup>1</sup>  I'm looking for a similarly *compact* idiom to create a ***set*** in JavaScript.  (NB: I am ***not*** interested in merely creating a list of strings.)

I understand that the standard approach to sets in JS is to use objects (keys are set elements, values immaterial), but I have not hit upon a comparably succinct way to create such a set in JS.

FWIW, the idiom I'm looking for is intended for a bookmarklet (hence the emphasis on succinctness).

Thanks!

<sup>1</sup> For those unfamiliar with Python, the inner expression just evaluates to the list of strings obtained by splitting the invoking string object at the whitespace; this list is then the argument to the `set` constructor.

Edit: emphasized that I'm looking for a ***set*** (i.e. ***object***), not a list of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a `set` type but you need a helper function to easily create it from a string (or from an `Array`).

Here's such a helper function which will allow you to call `.set()` on a string and get an object mapping the items from the string to some value (`true` if none is specified):

```
String.prototype.set = function(val) {
    var items = this.split(' '),
        len = items.length,
        obj = {},
        i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        obj[items[i]] = val === undefined ? true : val;
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Demo:

```
> 'pdf ppt tif tiff jpg jpeg'.set()
{ pdf: true,
  ppt: true,
  tif: true,
  tiff: true,
  jpg: true,
  jpeg: true }
```

Since you prefer something succinct, this might be a solution for you if you only need it for a single string:

```
var set = (function(s){ var obj = {}; for(var i = 0, elems = s.split(' '), l = elems.length; i < l; i++) obj[elems[i]] = 1; return obj; })('pdf ppt tif tiff jpg jpeg');
```

In that case I would consider simply using an object literal though... that's most likely the shortest solution unless you have a ton of elements.

Comment: No, I'm looking for an *object* whose *keys* (i.e. attribute names) are the strings generated by the split.

Comment: That's not possible without a helper function.

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript 5th Edition has [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
'pdf ppt tif tiff jpg jpeg'.split(' ').reduce(function(d,v){
    return d[v] = true,d
}, {});

Object
jpeg: true
jpg: true
pdf: true
ppt: true
tif: true
tiff: true
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: `.reduce()` requires IE9 in case it matters for you.

Comment: @ThiefMaster legacy browser fallback is up to OP if he needs it